# Beamer & MetaUML - can't see any diagram

Tags: beamer, metauml

On compilation, I just see

[image]

Why isn't the class visible? Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\title{Something}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section[Outline]{}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{something}
\subsection{Class Diagram}
\frame
{
\frametitle{Frame 1}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{mpost}[mpsettings=input metauml;]
            Usecase.U("Authenticate user",
            "by name, password");
            drawObject(U);        
        \end{mpost}
        \caption{Something}
    \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In section 5 of the documentation of `gmp` you find

> `\usempxclass [⟨options⟩] {⟨class⟩}`
>   This has the same syntax as `\documentclass`. Its purpose is to declare the class used for the runs of TeX or LaTeX for preparing the `mpx` files which METAPOST needs to draw the text labels. It should be not necessary to change it from the default (which is article). But if you are using a non standard class with a non standard type size (i.e., not 10, 11 or 12 point size), then you will need to declare a class, otherwise your labels will be typeset in 10 point type.

I didn't test the package with `beamer`, actually. But it falls in this category, so you can solve the problem by stating

```
\usempxclass{article}
```

in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}
\usempxclass{article}

\usetheme{Montpellier}
\title{Something}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section[Outline]{}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{something}
\subsection{Class Diagram}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 1}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{mpost}[mpsettings=input metauml]
  Usecase.U("Authenticate user",
   "by name, password");
   drawObject(U);        
\end{mpost}
\caption{Something}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for reading the manual (perhaps that should have been -1 for reading a manual)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

You need to use

```
pdflatex -shell-escape   yourfile
```

to allow the mp back end.

Also apparently for `beamer` you need to set the pointsize:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\def\@ptsize{10}
\makeatother
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\title{Something}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section[Outline]{}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{something}
\subsection{Class Diagram}
\frame
{
\frametitle{Frame 1}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{mpost}[mpsettings=input metauml;]
            Usecase.U("Authenticate user",
            "by name, password");
            drawObject(U);        
        \end{mpost}
        \caption{Something}
    \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```